# Unattended silent install of Java on OS X Lion/Mountain Lion (OS X 10.7, 10.8)

Tags: mac-osx, java, installation, automated-install, osx-lion

As Java is not installed by defaults on Lion and Mountain Lion systems (OS X 10.7, 10.8) I would like to deploy it to all machines on our network. I understand that I can simply download the .pkg and remote install it through Apple Remote Desktop. However, I am wondering if there is a way to send a remote command through Apple Remote Desktop to do a silent, unattended install.

Are there options for the 'java' command to do this? I know that if I am on a client machine and I type 'java' at the command line it will invoke an on demand installation, but it requires user action to click the "OK" button.

Thank you.

Comment: When you do the remote install through Apple Remote Desktop, is it non-silent?

Comment: Are you trying to install the browser plugin or just have Java on the computer to run Java apps?

Answer (score -1):

we can install java with brew cask.

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
brew casek install java
```

Comment: This assumes brew is already installed/being used.